# How to handle animation loops in assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm working on a text based animation in assembly where a large number of screen refreshes are required to make it smooth as possible and simulate bouncing physics. I use `int 1ah` calls to control the screen refresh delays and to make the shape appear as if it slows down reaching its peaks and speeds up as it falls back down. There is also a separate banner that is put to the screen after each `CALL CLEAR`.

I wrote the code that handles the moving shape's code and it worked as expected. When I added the additional code that puts a stationary banner on the screen it locks dosbox up after a certain point.

There are eight variations of the following code contained in a larger loop. It runs fine until I add the `;PRINT BANNER` to the seventh inner loop. Actually, it breaks on the first `LEA` in the below loop which wasn't there when testing w/o the banner.

```
  .REPEAT
       LEA     SI,SHAPE
       MOV     DH,ROW
       MOV     DL,COL
       CALL    CLEAR
       CALL    PUTSHAPE
       ;PRINT BANNER
       LEA     SI,BANNER            
       MOV     DH,25
       MOV     DL,39
       CALL    PUTSHAPE
       ;END BANNER
       MOV     TIME, 1
       MOV     AH, 0
       INT     1AH  
       ADD     TIME, DX
       .WHILE    DX < TIME
            MOV       AH, 0
            INT       1AH
       .ENDW                                       
       ADD  COL, 2
       SUB  ROW, 4
       DEC  D7
       MOV  CX, D7
       MOV  TIME, 0
  .UNTILCXZ
```

Am I expecting too much too fast here? I've tried to rearrange the code to call the second `LEA` after the delay and a host of other suggestions to problems not exactly pertaining to text based animation and definitely using instructions I can't follow. I'm a serious assembly beginner learning from a book that utilizes custom libraries. I tried the program out on my 32bit Win 7 Pro running from the command prompt and got an NTVDM.EXE error. Any ideas or insights on obvious issues with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my implementation was the looped `INT 1AH` (clock) calls. Windows complains when you don't allow it some time to do its thing.

**The solution to this** would be to provide an external procedure that calls `INT 1AH` returning the ticker value in a register. Then storing it in a value to ensure it does not get clobbered through procedure calls. Finally check it against the returned values from the external procedure calls contained in a loop like so...

```
       MOV     TIME, 1      ;The value moved into time determines speed
       CALL    DELAY        ;DELAY = INT 1AH call which puts the lower 1/2 
       ADD     TIME, DX     ;of the system clock into DX. Add it to TIME
       .WHILE    DX < TIME
            CALL DELAY      ;Loops call to the DELAY procedure testing DX
       .ENDW                ;against TIME + Original DELAY call
```

Adding the loop to another sub procedure in the DELAY.asm works as well.